# Will WKC running on-premise leverage StoredIQ for data connectors or does it leverage connectors in IBM Governance Catalog IGC?

Tags: watson-knowledge-catalog, data-governance

Will WKC running on-premise leverage StoredIQ for data connectors or does it leverage connectors in IGC?

Answer (score 0):

WKC running on-premises support the same connectors as those available in WKC as a public Saas in IBM Cloud.

You can find the full list of supported connectors for WKC on-prem [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZJPZ_11.7.0/wsj/manage-data/conn_types.html).